# tikz: Black hole eats pictures

Tags: tikz-pgf

While playing around with shadings I accidentally created a black hole (a zero-width rectangle) which ate all my pictures and text on the page:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
Still there: 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=red] (0,0)rectangle(2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}

The black hole:
\begin{tikzpicture}%zero width rectangle with shading:
\draw[left color=red, right color=blue] (2,0) rectangle (2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}

A picture lost in the black hole:
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=blue] (0,0)rectangle(2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}

Some text lost in the black hole.
\end{document}
```

There are no errors in the log. The black hole ends with the page. I get it with all engines. The pdf opens without problem but gsview complains and don't open the ps.

I made a bug report but perhaps someone here is interested to find out what's going on.

Comment: A red/blue shaded black hole!

Comment: I was rather disappointed that the black hole didn't eat anything in my tests... You can see yourself [here](https://www.writelatex.com/122157cjdqff). +1 nevertheless for the funny title and description

Comment: @JLDiaz: It seems to depend on the viewer. I get it with reader 8 + 9 but not with sumatra.

Comment: I don't get a "black hole" with evince. Just a zero width rectangle.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I get no black hole with OSX's preview either.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer No black hole with OSX's preview and Skim but I get the black hole with Adobe reader !. I knew that Windows was the dark side now I have a confirmation but I need to add Adobe too :)

Comment: No problem with Sumatra or AR (on MikTeX, TikZ CVS 2.10).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer More seriously. I try some experiments with Adobe Reader. I used  rectangle `(2,0) rectangle (2,2)` but without shading and the black hole disappears. I get a null rectangle. The wrong code seems to come from the shading effect with null dimensions.

Comment: @AlainMatthes: I just installed adobe 11 and there is no longer a black hole (pity ;-)). But it remains the error with gsview so I think that there is something problematic in the code but that most viewers either ignore or recover somehow.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The shading code is very complex, I supposed it's based on postscript code ( there are some terrific examples in the pgfmanual). It's not very strange to get an error when you try to shade an empty surface. Perhaps it's only a lack of test in a routine.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it with texlive-2012, however, smth. strange is seen if one uses "standalone" package instead of "artcile"

Comment: The question title would be better for April 1st. `:-)`

Answer (score 2):

I think that the problem is that you set the x dimension of the second rectancular at 0. Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
Still there: 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=red] (0,0)rectangle(2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}

The black hole:
\begin{tikzpicture}%zero width rectangle with shading:
\draw[left color=red, right color=blue] (2,0) rectangle (4,2);
\end{tikzpicture}

A picture lost in the black hole:
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=blue] (0,0)rectangle(2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}

Some text lost in the black hole.
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)